# Matrix and geometry

Tags: matrices, matrix-equations

If the three points $A(1; a; b)$         $B(a;2 ;b)$  $C(a; b; 3)$ are aligned, what is the value of $a+b$ ? 
I think that the range of this matrix should be equal to one:
$$\begin{pmatrix} 
x_b-x_a & y_b-y_a & z_b-z_a\\
x_c-x_a& y_c-y_a & z_c-z_a
\end{pmatrix}
\quad$$
$$\begin{pmatrix} 
a-1 & 2-a & 0 \\
a-1 & b-a & 3-b
\end{pmatrix}
\quad$$
As a consequence the determinants of the submatrices $2\times2$ should be zero.
$$\begin{pmatrix} 
a-1 & 0\\
a-1 & 3-b 
\end{pmatrix}
\quad$$
$$\begin{pmatrix} 
2-a & 0 \\
b-a & 3-b
\end{pmatrix}
\quad$$
$$\begin{pmatrix} 
a-1 & 2-a  \\
a-1 & b-a 
\end{pmatrix}
\quad$$
We have $$(a-1)(3-b)=0$$ $$(a-2)(3-b)=0$$ $$(a-1)(b-a)-(2-a)(a-1)=0$$ so $a=1$ and $b=3$

We get $a+b=4$ is that right ?

Comment: Sorry, but I don't see how the three points that you give can be aligned. There has to be some typo.

Comment: I edited the question, I hope that now it is more clear.

Comment: It is not understandable: you do not explain how you have built your first matrix !

Comment: Sorry, I edited the question.

Answer (score 0):

You have the formula for determinant wrong. It should be $(a-1)(3-b)=0$. Also, look at you last equation:$$2-a=b-3$$ From here you get $a+b=5$. This is wrong

You have three submatrices, not 2
$$\begin{pmatrix} 
a-1 & 0\\
a-1 & 3-b 
\end{pmatrix}
$$
$$\begin{pmatrix} 
2-a & 0 \\
b-a & 3-b
\end{pmatrix}
$$
$$\begin{pmatrix} 
a-1 &2-a  \\
a-1&b-a 
\end{pmatrix}
$$
Then from the determinant of the first matrix you get $a=1$ or $b=3$. In the second determinant you get $a=2$ or $b=3$. Obviously these two determinants can be $0$ only if $b=3$. In the last determinant you get $$(a-1)[(3-a)-(2-a)]=0$$ so $a=1$

Comment: Yes, I made a stupid mistake while I was editing the question.

Comment: I edited the question, I would like to know if it is correct the method to calculate a+b.

Comment: It's fine. That's the same answer I wrote